# How to get cell address based on value of another cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column in date format (A column).

In the `E1` cell, I enter a certain date value, and in the cell below—`E2`—I need to get the cell address of the cell in column A which is equal to the specified date.

For example, the output should be `A35`.

I'm trying with the `=ADDRESS` function, but not having success. Can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Answer

The following formula should produce the behaviour you want:

```
=ADDRESS(MATCH(E1,A:A,0),1,4)
```

### Explanation

`=MATCH` searches a specified range for a specified value, and returns the index of that value (it's row number). In this case, the value to search for is in `E1`, and the range to search through is `A:A`.

`=ADDRESS` determines the A1 notation of a specific row and column. In this case, the row is determined by `=MATCH` and the column is column 1 (or column A). The `4` tells `=ADDRESS` to return the relative cell reference rather than the absolute cell reference (`A35` instead of `$A$35`).

Functions used:

- [=MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en)
- [=ADDRESS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093308?hl=en)

Comment: I tried and not success, It shows "Error" :/

Comment: @Valleze Could update your question to include some sample data to give a better idea of what your issue is? "Error" is not much information to work with.

Comment: Oh, I've succeeded now. I just changed all the "," to ";" Thank you my friend. You just saved my day.

Comment: @Valleze Depending on your locale, Sheets might prefer commas or semicolons to separate arguments in a function. Glad that fixed things for you.